# Android code to show Arabic keyboard

Tags: android

I am developing an application where I have to change the Android keyboard on a button click. I want to show Arabic keyboard. But my device does not have Arabic language. English keyboard is being shown fine. But I am not able to show Arabic keyboard. Is there any way to accomplish this. Please share some idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your device SDK version lower than 2.3?

Comment: @LazyNinja Is there any way to show Arabic keyboard in 2.2..?

Comment: I am afraid for SDK below 2.3 you have to install a third party application like this one https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gokeyboard.langpack.ar&hl=en .

Comment: @LazyNinja Thanks for the link. But I can not use any third party application. But I am ready to change my sdk to 2.3. So if I use android sdk 2.3 then how can I solve this problem?